# Django Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting web | TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to dockerize my Django application. My configs are the following:

**settings.py**

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'DB_NAME',
        'USER': 'DB_USER',
        'PASSWORD': 'DB_PASSWORD',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

**.env file**

```
POSTGRES_USER='DB_USER'
POSTGRES_PASSWORD='DB_PASSWORD'
POSTGRES_DB='DB_NAME'
POSTGRES_HOST='localhost'
POSTGRES_PORT='5432'
```

**Dockerfile.web**

```
FROM python:3.9-bullseye

WORKDIR /app

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

COPY csgo .

RUN apt-get update -y \
    && apt-get upgrade -y pip \
    && pip install --upgrade pip \
    && pip install -r requirements.txt

CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    container_name: web
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.web
    env_file:
      - .env
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - '8000:8000'
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: postgres:13
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    env_file:
      - .env

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

Now, when I `docker-compose up` all appear to be working fine besides connection to the database. I get this error:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
web           |         Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
web           |         TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
web           | could not connect to server: Cannot assign requested address
web           |         Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
web           |         TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Can you please help me solve this problem? Additionally, I would be grateful for broader explanation about the **localhost** definition in docker containers and its connections.

Comment: `POSTGRES_HOST='db'`, localhost is as always, the local loopback of a machine the fact that it is a container does not differ. So, different container means It is not localhost anymore.

Comment: Please don't re-ask the same question again; if you believe your original isn't a duplicate, please clarify on the original question.  You may also be looking for [What does localhost means inside a Docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50278632/what-does-localhost-means-inside-a-docker-container).

Comment: In my case had to change the host in `settings.py` to `'HOST': 'postgres'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a Docker context, `localhost` means the container itself.

Docker compose sets up a docker bridge network and connects the containers to it. From one container, you can connect to another container using it's service name.

So you need to use `db` as the hostname for the database, like this

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'DB_NAME',
        'USER': 'DB_USER',
        'PASSWORD': 'DB_PASSWORD',
        'HOST': 'db',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

As far as I can see, you don't use the environment variables, but you might need to change it there as well.

Comment: I have used it, then came up with idea that env_file is enough to meet env variable expectations, no?

Comment: Yeah bro, thanks. Your answer was really helpful, I got understanding of concepts of docker and its container! Additionally, I am getting a new error, heh. Could you help me solve it? ```django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "DB_USER"```

Comment: I hate this kind of errors. I don't understand how do I connect to a database. And if I create that database with my own password, then why it raises this auth error?